# Is there any way to use views contextual filters in block configuration?

Tags: views, 8, taxonomy-terms

For my situation, i need to create views for taxonomy terms content listing, I have created that with blocks. I am using contextual filter in that views to filter the content with taxonomy terms dynamically.

Is there any way to give value for contextual filter from block configuration page ?

If we have that options, then it would save me from creating separate blocks for each terms.

Contextual filter configuration :
[image]

My question is can i give value for the contextual filter from the block configuration page ?

Comment: just to clarify things, you created a **view block**?

Comment: @NoSssweat Yes,

Comment: How is your contextual filter setup? What do you have for **WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT IN THE URL** ???

Comment: @NoSssweat updated the question check it :)

Answer (score 2):

The contextual filter is not possible to be exposed on a block. It is only possible with filter criteria.

The other posibility is use a taxonomy term view and use the module [Taxonomy menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu) or [Taxonomy menu block](https://www.drupal.org/project/taxonomy_menu_block) to show a list of taxonomy terms on a block.